# Stokes theorem question: finding the right modeling approach and choosing between polar and cartesian coordinates

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, vectors, vector-analysis, spherical-coordinates

I have imagined a vector field describing [helices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helix) moving at different speeds:

$V(x, y, z, z_0) = <cz_0, a \  sin(y\ k\ z_0), b \ cos(z\ k\ z_0)> \ \forall x,y,z \ s.t. y^2+(z_0-z)^2=1, $

I did my best to describe the vector speed $V$ of the flow in a field of many helixes. My trick was to consider each helix separately  The helical flow increases with speed as $z$ increases. $x$ is horizontal distance from the origin and $z_0$ measures the centerline of the helix in terms of vertical distance (the $z$ direction) from the origin. The horizontal speed is proportional to the vertical position: $\frac{\delta V_x}{\delta z_0}=c$.  Similarly, I did my best to model the swirling part of the helical motion as being proportional to the height. The idea is that helixes which are lower should generally move slower that the helixes which are higher up.

I am having difficulty applying Stoke's theorem to this problem. I am interested in the net flux associated with some control volume surrounding these helixes. Here, I try to use a spherical ($\theta=arccos(\frac{x}{y})$ and $\phi=arccos(\frac{x}{z})$) control volume:

$ \int V \bullet\hat{dr} = \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \Delta \times V d\phi d\theta = $

$ \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi}  <\frac{\delta }{\delta x}, \frac{\delta }{\delta y}, \frac{\delta }{\delta z}> \times <cz_0, a \  sin(y\ k\ z_0), b \ cos(z\ k\ z_0)> d\phi d\theta =$

$\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} $

$<(\frac{\delta }{\delta y} b \ cos(z\ k\ z_0) - \frac{\delta }{\delta z} a \  sin(y\ k\ z_0)), (\frac{\delta }{\delta z} cz_0 - \frac{\delta }{\delta x}  b \ cos(z\ k\ z_0)), (\frac{\delta }{\delta x} a \  sin(y\ k\ z_0) - \frac{\delta }{\delta y} cz_0) > d\phi d\theta$

I am not sure how to proceed from here. Is there a better way to formulate this problem? Am I applying Stoke's theorem correctly? While an analytical solution would be ideal, I am not sure how to even solve this numerically.

**Edit**
Really I only modeled one of these cylinders. I want to model many (infinite) cylinders with these velocity properties. I think a cylinder is a good surrogate for a helix here. I think I can do that by integrating across $z_0$ assuming a maximum helix centerline height $Z$.

$V(x, y, z) = \int_0^Z <cz_0, a \  sin(y\ k\ z_0), b \ cos(z\ k\ z_0)> dz_0\ \forall x,y,z \in R$

$V(x,y,z) = <c \frac{Z^2}{2}, \frac{a_2}{y} \  (cos(y\ k\ Z)-1), \frac{b_2}{z} \ sin(z\ k\ Z)> $

Comment: You're missing a dot product between the curl of the field and the differential normal vector.  That's your problem here.

Comment: Aside from this issue, you can only used Stokes on a closed path.  Thus path is not closed.

Comment: The more I look at this, the less sense it makes. V represents either the path or the field.  It is nonsense to have it represent both.

Comment: @Paul I should have described $V$ as a function of $x$,$y$, $z$, and $z_0$, not  as $V(x,z_0)$. I also had $b cos(y k z_0) \hat{k}$ instead of $b cos(y k z_0) \hat{k}$. I made these edits —does my question make more sense now?

Comment: Why isn't $\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} d\theta d\pi$ a closed path?

Comment: $\Delta = \nabla^2$ is the symbol for the laplacian which is a scalar operator (and hence has no cross product) , the symbol for partial derivatives is \partial $\partial$.

Comment: Thank you. I am struggling with the notation.

Comment: You also need to give us the surface over which you intend to use stokes theorem (so far I see a cylinder centered on the x axis)

Comment: I think I am indifferent to the shape of the control surface—I'm interested in the direction of the net flux. I thought it would be best to use a sphere.

Comment: What I want to do is consider at least two cylinders with radial and forward speeds that increase with height. I'm starting to see that my $z_0$ trick doesn't allow for more than one cylinder.

Comment: Question is this based on a real world problem? Or is this some thought experiment, because it seems difficult to desribe fully

Comment: Yes it's based on a real-world problem. I am imagining an eddy being formed by flow passing across a rotating turbine blade, where the fluid velocity increases with height. I suspect that the difference in rotational velocity of the top and bottom of the eddy causes a net velocity which can be related to the direction of the turbine's rotation.